# IIS 6.0 Not loading SessionState for .NET 3.5 Application using HttpHandler

Tags: .net, iis-6, httphandler, session-state

QA and Dev enviroments work perfectly.
Handlers all implement the IRequiresSessionState marker.

Config File contains:

```
<pages enableSessionState="true">
```

and

```
<sessionState cookieless="AutoDetect" mode="InProc" timeout="20" />
```

IIS has session state enabled in application properties and Application is running in its own Application Pool....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So big difference in IIS 6 vs IIS 7.

The Session module need to be stated in the httpModules config section, as VS2008 adds a , and adding it to the web.server section does nothing...

```
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
```